# No longer able to connect by SSH

Tags: mysql, ssh, google-cloud-platform

I'm using Google cloud with a couple of instances deployed.

I was trying to resolve an issue with the MySQL database on the server and I couldn't get MySQL to start so I resorted to restarting the instance.

I noticed that when it came back up, the external ip address appeared to have changed so I changed it from ephemeral to static as the instance is used to host a website.

I now can't connect via SSH to the server - I get this in the logs:

```
Mar  4 17:24:09 puntcambridge-puntcambridge-ippn sshd[3419]: Invalid user faina from 184.173.54.130
Mar  4 17:24:09 puntcambridge-puntcambridge-ippn sshd[3419]: input_userauth_request: invalid user faina [preauth]
Mar  4 17:24:10 puntcambridge-puntcambridge-ippn sshd[3419]: Received disconnect from 184.173.54.130: 11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Mar  4 17:24:16 puntcambridge-puntcambridge-ippn sshd[3421]: Connection closed by 173.194.92.32 [preauth]
Mar  4 17:24:29 puntcambridge-puntcambridge-ippn sshd[3423]: Connection closed by 173.194.92.35 [preauth]
Mar  4 17:24:44 puntcambridge-puntcambridge-ippn sshd[3425]: Connection closed by 173.194.92.35 [preauth]
Mar  4 17:24:47 puntcambridge-puntcambridge-ippn collectd[2527]: mysql plugin: Failed to connect to database <none> at server localhost: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)
Mar  4 17:24:47 puntcambridge-puntcambridge-ippn collectd[2527]: read-function of plugin `mysql-wpdatabase' failed. Will suspend it for 960.000 seconds.
Mar  4 17:25:08 puntcambridge-puntcambridge-ippn sshd[3436]: Connection closed by 173.194.92.34 [preauth]
Mar  4 17:25:46 puntcambridge-puntcambridge-ippn sshd[3439]: Connection closed by 173.194.92.36 [preauth]
Mar  4 17:25:47 puntcambridge-puntcambridge-ippn sshd[3440]: Connection closed by 173.194.92.33 [preauth]
Mar  4 17:26:57 puntcambridge-puntcambridge-ippn sshd[3453]: Connection closed by 173.194.92.36 [preauth]
Mar  4 17:27:09 puntcambridge-puntcambridge-ippn sshd[3464]: Connection closed by 173.194.92.32 [preauth]
Mar  4 17:27:47 puntcambridge-puntcambridge-ippn sshd[3467]: Invalid user faina from 184.173.54.130
Mar  4 17:27:47 puntcambridge-puntcambridge-ippn sshd[3467]: input_userauth_request: invalid user faina [preauth]
Mar  4 17:27:47 puntcambridge-puntcambridge-ippn sshd[3467]: Received disconnect from 184.173.54.130: 11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Mar  4 17:29:10 puntcambridge-puntcambridge-ippn sshd[3479]: Connection closed by 173.194.92.35 [preauth]
Mar  4 17:30:24 puntcambridge-puntcambridge-ippn sshd[3491]: Connection closed by 173.194.92.36 [preauth]
Mar  4 17:31:24 puntcambridge-puntcambridge-ippn sshd[3503]: Invalid user faina from 184.173.54.130
Mar  4 17:31:24 puntcambridge-puntcambridge-ippn sshd[3503]: input_userauth_request: invalid user faina [preauth]
Mar  4 17:31:24 puntcambridge-puntcambridge-ippn sshd[3503]: Received disconnect from 184.173.54.130: 11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Mar  4 17:32:12 puntcambridge-puntcambridge-ippn sshd[3515]: Connection closed by 74.125.17.96 [preauth]
Mar  4 17:32:21 puntcambridge-puntcambridge-ippn sshd[3517]: Connection closed by 74.125.73.36 [preauth]
Mar  4 17:32:23 puntcambridge-puntcambridge-ippn sshd[3519]: Connection closed by 74.125.73.100 [preauth]
Mar  4 17:32:35 puntcambridge-puntcambridge-ippn sshd[3521]: Connection closed by 74.125.17.33 [preauth]
Mar  4 17:32:45 puntcambridge-puntcambridge-ippn sshd[3532]: Connection closed by 74.125.73.99 [preauth]
Mar  4 17:32:58 puntcambridge-puntcambridge-ippn sshd[3535]: Connection closed by 74.125.73.98 [preauth]
Mar  4 17:33:12 puntcambridge-puntcambridge-ippn sshd[3537]: Connection closed by 74.125.47.161 [preauth]
Mar  4 17:33:55 puntcambridge-puntcambridge-ippn sshd[3548]: Connection closed by 74.125.73.163 [preauth]
Mar  4 17:34:02 puntcambridge-puntcambridge-ippn sshd[3551]: Connection closed by 74.125.17.32 [preauth]
Mar  4 17:34:10 puntcambridge-puntcambridge-ippn sshd[3553]: Connection closed by 74.125.17.99 [preauth]
Mar  4 17:34:19 puntcambridge-puntcambridge-ippn sshd[3555]: Connection closed by 74.125.73.33 [preauth]
Mar  4 17:34:31 puntcambridge-puntcambridge-ippn sshd[3557]: Connection closed by 74.125.73.98 [preauth]
```

and the SSH client keeps timing out. I'm a little out of my depth here and not sure where to start in order to resolve this so any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Happy to provide whatever additional information would help.

Thanks,

Comment: how do you connect? What means "keeps timing out"? What is not understandable on `invalid user faina` error message?

Comment: Increase the log verbosity on the server.

Comment: It looks like invalid username is being used from what I see.  Are you certain the restore didn't revert back to before the username was created?

Comment: thanks for the responses. I'm not sure what those other login attempts are, guessing bots attempting to get into the server? I have managed to login by creating a new user. Now I am going to try to figure out what the problem is with mysql. I am concerned that the vm may have been compromised somehow

Comment: I can see from your comments that you have resolved this issue. Please consider posting a self-answer so the community can benefit.

Answer (score 1):

Community wiki post:

The solution found by the original poster was to recreate a new user in order to log back into his MySQL server. It is possible that upon restoring the instance, an altered set of the original user’s credentials has been stored and caused the error.

Comment: I did create a new user (for SSH) not for MySQL and that allowed me to log back in. Unfortunately (as this was a while ago) I can't be more specific as I don't remember the exact process I went through.